# delete data from sqlite database but data is persists

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a local sqlite database in my android application that includes links to some images.
When the user tries to delete the specific image, the url in the database is deleted but the application is still showing it.  When the user goes to another activity and he comes back the activity is not showing that image.
so what is problem?
here is my code:

```
            getFileList();
            G.database.execSQL("DELETE FROM favourites WHERE fav_url='" + imageList.get(counter).Url + "'");
            imageList.remove(counter);
            getFileList();
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://192.168.1.2/fashionable/images" + imageList.get(counter + 2).Url);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                imgShowImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

and getFileList() method:

```
 private void getFileList() {
    Cursor cursor = G.database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM favourites", null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        StructImages image = new StructImages();
        image.Url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fav_url"));
        imageList.add(image);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: What probably is happening is that you delete the image from the database but you are not drawing again the view, when you are coming back the image is shown back because you are building again the view.

Comment: i used the imgShowImage.invalidate() But the problem persists

Comment: could show your code of the activity? I what I assumed correct?